# Why are my strings accepted into int values in sql db?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to better learn SQL and so I started from the beginning using sqlite3. When I tried to insert a string value into a value that was designated to be an int it worked perfectly. Can someone explain how this is possible?

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE entertainment(num INT, show TEXT, myRating INT);
INSERT INTO "entertainment" VALUES(1,'Mr. Robot',10);
INSERT INTO "entertainment" VALUES(7,'Narcos','el classic');
INSERT INTO "entertainment" VALUES(8,'Suits',7);
INSERT INTO "entertainment" VALUES(9,'Friends',"classic");
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite3 is very flexible in this regard. In a nutshell, sqlite3 will convert the data as necessary or store it as it, regardless of the type you specify. However, by specifying data types, sqlite3 will use that information to store the data as efficiently as it can.

When you define a column as INTEGER, sqlite3 assigns a type affinity of INTEGER to the column. There is also a NUMERIC type affinity.

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible. For conversions between TEXT and REAL storage classes, SQLite considers the conversion to be lossless and reversible if the first 15 significant decimal digits of the number are preserved. If the lossless conversion of TEXT to INTEGER or REAL is not possible then the value is stored using the TEXT storage class. No attempt is made to convert NULL or BLOB values.

And INTEGER affinity is defined as follows:

> A column that uses INTEGER affinity behaves the same as a column with NUMERIC affinity. The difference between INTEGER and NUMERIC affinity is only evident in a CAST expression.

In your case, sqlite3 won't convert the text but store it using the TEXT storage class.

See the [Datatypes](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) page from the SQLite reference for more details on data types, storage class and type affinity.

Answer (score 0):

https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q3

> (3) SQLite lets me insert a string into a database column of type integer!
>
> This is a feature, not a bug. SQLite uses dynamic typing. It does not enforce data type constraints. Data of any type can (usually) be inserted into any column. You can put arbitrary length strings into integer columns, floating point numbers in boolean columns, or dates in character columns. The datatype you assign to a column in the CREATE TABLE command does not restrict what data can be put into that column. Every column is able to hold an arbitrary length string. (There is one exception: Columns of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY may only hold a 64-bit signed integer. An error will result if you try to put anything other than an integer into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column.)
>
> But SQLite does use the declared type of a column as a hint that you prefer values in that format. So, for example, if a column is of type INTEGER and you try to insert a string into that column, SQLite will attempt to convert the string into an integer. If it can, it inserts the integer instead. If not, it inserts the string. This feature is called type affinity.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q3)

> This is a feature, not a bug. SQLite uses dynamic typing. It does not enforce data type constraints. Data of any type can (usually) be inserted into any column. You can put arbitrary length strings into integer columns, floating point numbers in boolean columns, or dates in character columns.